# Which kinds of variables are Lasso or Ridge selected?

Tags: machine-learning, regression, artificial-intelligence, data-science

I understand how Lasso or Ridge are trying to make slopes flatter. But do all the coefficients of different features punished in a same rate? Like if without Lasso the regression is y=x+2z, then both of the coefficients will become half of the previous: y=0.5x+z? Or like the features with a less correlation with the dependent variable are punished more?

Answer (score 0):

Lasso and Ridge regression use what's called L1 and L2 regularization.
Read more here: https://towardsdatascience.com/l1-and-l2-regularization-methods-ce25e7fc831c